# Vega-lite bar chart cornerRadiusEnd happening at axis end for negative values

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I have plotted the Horizontal Bar Chart with Negative Values, when I rounded the edges, for negative side, its happening at axis side

```
    {"mark": {"type": "bar", 
           "cornerRadiusEnd": 100
           }},
```

[image]

The top bar roundness should be on the other side, Is it possible to do that
https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/bar_negative_horizontal_label.html

Also

```
"align": {"expr": "datum.mean < 0 ? 'right' : 'left'"},
```

not working,
if mean is less than zero, its in right, but for positive value also its in right
[image]
for

```
"align": {"expr": "datum.mean < 0 ? 'left' : 'right'"},
```

[image]
How to get both values inside?

Answer (score 1):

The `cornerRadius` part should be achievable using `expr`, I tried doing for `fill` which is showing different color based on condition but it didn't work for `cornerRadius` configs, it might be a bug. I think the same thing your tried for `align` is also working in the bar chart sample you provided, but without your config I cannot understand why the `align` is not working for you.

You can check the sample code below or the [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289AEEABEyTrDsU5kMB3OjEOy+O0oeJJBDNZUMB1OOaRZQxgaVUN6fyQADxoIQ2U2ZBog4UcFQ0DlQ2SITDgkLIYISPM5ZTpdd0MyTSyoNkE2M0w2ePUkawzDAC84dVaTYtS4SkUVJEwUVFA3DzU0AG1QKZB9MaY0fgAmAA4AXwVltBAAIXW0MTEDo-QAYXPUfgBmJ+uQFYARB4BOAEY3lYAUQeO3+h3exwAYg8xK9wSsAOIPfi-b4A44ACRBAHZ0egAJIwrZ7AC6BxA9VkADMaGQtmhQMh1ABrBkUpqOdQAJQKNCKaC2AAY9uS4LJ6uVZGQ2QBPNk0uCCZTHFBKTAynBwY6yRLJdxjaKxNkJJJ6KnuYpqmhQZkQNDmwSWkCCJBMRX6KWCLWoQVKF1uwQABQKkulqAALCKlFF5TRFcr0Bs1RrvSAAI4MQI6SbOLVKaDub2gHAh5JhoUi8kumV9RaM0ys6YgdWa44mdRjerqTk88pFQGyBOgOBRHAd9DKCYMBCUJiGAA8hkFhgA-EvDKhDDtBSByTTBII2SOx8dJ5hp7OF+u1wBydRwZQ3jeGG81OBim+7pRdnu8oonNhsESLlaSwI9R3HcZzxnOdF2XNdw2XTcd3JH8+l7PkIAAFTYHAQLIMCm2PSCzwvWDr0MRDnxQqN6xZNkW1TPIokwA1hDIPRhwg08pxgq94JfTQCMwJ9NxvL0qREr8VBjIjuInXjLzg1dDG2Z96SjEAxQlMsGJHVimwVJU2zGRjjgzLM6AmGhSF3EUySAA):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A bar chart with negative values. We can hide the axis domain line, and instead use a conditional grid color to draw a zero baseline.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"a": "A", "b": -28},
      {"a": "B", "b": 55},
      {"a": "C", "b": -33},
      {"a": "D", "b": 91},
      {"a": "E", "b": 81},
      {"a": "F", "b": 53},
      {"a": "G", "b": -19},
      {"a": "H", "b": 87},
      {"a": "I", "b": 52}
    ]
  },
  "config2": {"mark": {"cornerRadius": 20}},
  "encoding": {
    "y": {
      "field": "a",
      "type": "nominal",
      "axis": {
        "domain": false,
        "ticks": false,
        "labelAngle": 0,
        "labelPadding": 4
      }
    },
    "x": {
      "field": "b",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "scale": {"padding": 20}
    }
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "bar",
        "cornerRadiusEnd": {"expr": "datum.b < 0 ? 0 : 80"},
        "fill": {"expr": "datum.b < 0 ? 'red' : 'green'"},
        "cornerRadiusBottomRight": {"expr": "datum.b < 0 ? 40 : 0"},
        "cornerRadiusTopRight": {"expr": "datum.b < 0 ? 40 : 0"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "align": {"expr": "datum.b < 0 ? 'right' : 'left'"},
        "dx": {"expr": "datum.b < 0 ? -2 : 2"}
      },
      "encoding": {"text": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative"}}
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, regarding 'align', there is no difference in the code, but version I am using "vega-lite/v4.json" not sure whether v5 has that update

Comment: The version in schema doesn't matter as the vega-lite editor has the upgraded version.

Comment: I am running in kibana from elasticsearch data index, for me to check I have to update the elastic version I guess, because v5 showing error as "The input spec uses vega-lite v5, but current version of vega-lite is 4.17.0.", so for now not sure why thats happening

Comment: That's just a warning which is won't affect the execution so conclusion is your config is running properly in v5.